# Run Command Line & Command From VBS

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt

I need to run a command to copy a file from one location to another through Command Prompt using a vbs file. this is what I have however it keeps throwing an error at me.

```
'Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy "S:Claims\Sound.wav" "C:\WINDOWS\Media\Sound.wav"
Set oShell = Nothing'
```

The error i get is:

```
'Script: C:\******\command.vbs
Char: 30
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 80040401
```

Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error'

Please help :)

Answer (score 45):

The problem is on this line:

```
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy "S:Claims\Sound.wav" "C:\WINDOWS\Media\Sound.wav"
```

Your first quote next to "S:Claims" ends the string; you need to escape the quotes around your files with a second quote, like this:

```
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy ""S:\Claims\Sound.wav"" ""C:\WINDOWS\Media\Sound.wav"" "
```

You also have a typo in `S:Claims\Sound.wav`, should be `S:\Claims\Sound.wav`.

I also assume the apostrophe before `Dim oShell` and after `Set oShell = Nothing` are typos as well.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, that makes sense. Yeah the apostrophe's were typos. Works a treat! :)

Comment: s:claims\sound.wav is valid (file sound.wav under claims folder in current working folder on S drive) where S:\claims specify that claims folder is on the root (and maybe the same as s:claims)

Comment: Hi user1590368, Could you please mark this solution as the right answer?

Comment: I would rather [do this](http://pastie.org/private/j3kqoslwugfnodja9lc6hw#) (not sure if works) than what you or user1590368 is doing.

Answer (score 5):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C copy ""S:Claims\Sound.wav"" ""C:\WINDOWS\Media\Sound.wav"" "
```

Comment: if the file path doesn't contain blank space, you dont have to put qoute around filename.

Comment: You also missed the `S:Claims` typo.