# Passing a parameter to a subroutine

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a powerpoint file with the following macro:

```
Sub test(msg$)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

I have a vbscript file that looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
RunMacro

Sub RunMacro()

    Set ppApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open("test.pptm", 1)

    ppApp.Run "test.pptm!test ""my message here"" "

    ppApp.Quit

    Set ppPres = Nothing
    Set ppApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to pass the string parameter to the macro (no message box shows up in PPT). I'm guessing something is wrong with the number of quotation marks, but I've tried every permutation I could think of and nothing works. If I hard-code the message in the macro everything works fine.

Related (tried these, with no luck)

[How to call Run() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025843/vbscript-how-to-call-run-with-parameters)

[Shell.Run with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566540/vbscript-shell-run-with-arguments)

Comment: You are using powerpoints application.run, so I believe a comma, so app.run functionname, arg1,arg2   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744221.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744221.aspx). You're confusing the (VBScript) `WshShell.Run` method with the (VBA) `Application.Run` method.

Change this:

```
ppApp.Run "test.pptm!test ""my message here"" "
```

into this:

```
ppApp.Run "test.pptm!test", "my message here"
```