# Run Command line via VBS with parameters

Tags: command-line, vbscript

Having a hard time with this one. I can run the following command from a command prompt successfully, but can't get it working with a VB script.

From CMD:

1. Change directory to C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\
2. then run: vmrun.exe -T ws start "C:\Users\Office\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7\Windows 7.vmx" nogui

What I've tried in VBS:

```
Dim objShell, strPath1, strAttr, strPath2 
Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

strPath1 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"
strAttr1 = " -T ws start "
strAttr2 = "C:\Users\Office\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7\Windows 7.vmx"
strAttr3 = " nogui"

'WScript.Echo strPath1 & strAttr1 & """" & strAttr2 & """" & strAttr3 

objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & """" & strAttr2 & """" & strAttr3
```

The error I get is: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I think you need *double* double quote every path with spaces

Comment: Thanks! That was it. It just looked off when viewing the echo output, but it works :)

Comment: The full code ended up as: `Dim objShell, strPath1, strAttr1, strAttr2, strAttr3
Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

strPath1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"""
strAttr1 = " -T ws start "
strAttr2 = """C:\Users\Office\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7\Windows 7.vmx"""
strAttr3 = " nogui"

'WScript.Echo strPath1 & strAttr1 & strAttr2 & strAttr3

'objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & """" & strAttr2 & """" & strAttr3 

objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & strAttr2 & strAttr3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Command Line & Command From VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087470/run-command-line-command-from-vbs)

Answer (score 4):

Working Code ended up being:

```
Dim objShell, strPath1, strAttr1, strAttr2, strAttr3
Set objShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

strPath1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmrun.exe"""
strAttr1 = " -T ws start "
strAttr2 = """C:\Users\Office\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7\Windows 7.vmx"""
strAttr3 = " nogui"

objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & strAttr2 & strAttr3
```

Answer (score 0):

i would replace objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & """" & strAttr2 & """" & strAttr3

with

objShell.Run strPath1 & strAttr1 & chr(34) & strAttr2 & chr(34) & strAttr3

or include the chr(34) before and after the strAttr2 variable

strAttr2 = chr(34) & "C:\Users\Office\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7\Windows 7.vmx" & chr(34)

btw chr(34) = "

Comment: or create a variable that already has the quotes to concatenate cleaner 

var = chr(34) & strAttr2 & chr(34)