# Use VBS to run a program with parameters

Tags: vbscript

I'm a total vbs novice trying to perform the supposedly simple task of using a vbscript to run a single program (with parameters).

The path the to program is:
***C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe***
and the parameter switch that must go with it is:
***/Firefox:C:\Program Files\Firefox\Data\profile***

If I wrap both sections in quotes (due to the spaces in their paths) it gives the following combined single command:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe" "/Firefox:C:\Program Files\Firefox\Data\profile"`

If I then paste this into ***Start > Run*** it works exactly as I want.

I'm just trying to achieve the same thing from a vbs script instead of manually pasting into the ***Run*** box.

I do **not** want the command to run within a CMD console (as other questions on here have asked). All I am trying to do is to get `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe" "/Firefox:C:\Program Files\Firefox\Data\profile"` to work with the **shell.ShellExecute** line of the script below.

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject ("Wscript.shell")
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.ShellExecute  ** WHAT DO I PUT HERE? **
set shell=nothing
```

but try as I might, I just keep getting WSH "*Expected end of statement*" error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Command Line & Command From VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087470/run-command-line-command-from-vbs)

Answer (score 2):

***1.First :*** I recommend you Make it a habit to use this quote function
    to make it easy for you to quote variables in these situations !

***2. Second :*** You should use `MsgBox` or `Wscript.echo` in order to show
    and debug your variables easily !

```
Wscript.echo DblQuote("Hello World !")
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

So, I downloaded this application (speedyfox.exe) and i tested it on my **Windows 10 (32bits)**

So, here is what i tested and it works like a charm on my side :

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell,MyCommand,strProgramFiles,SpeedyFoxfile,Title
Title = "Execute SpeedyFox in Commandline"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
strProgramFiles = GetProgramFilesPath()
SpeedyFoxfile = strProgramFiles & "\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe"
MsgBox "Without Double Quotes" & vbCrlf & SpeedyFoxfile,vbInformation,Title
MsgBox "With Double Quotes" & vbCrlf & DblQuote(SpeedyFoxfile),vbInformation,Title
MyCommand = "CD /D "& DblQuote(strProgramFiles &"\SpeedyFox\") &"&"& DblQuote(SpeedyFoxfile) & " " & DblQuote("/Firefox:default") & " " & DblQuote("/Chrome:Default")
MsgBox MyCommand,vbInformation,Title
Call Execute(MyCommand) 
'-----------------------------------------
Function Execute(StrCmd)
   Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
   Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
   MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""'
   Result = ws.run(MyCmd,1,True)
   Execute = Result
End Function
'-----------------------------------------
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'-----------------------------------------
Function GetProgramFilesPath()
Dim ws,OsType,strProgramFiles
Set ws = createObject("WScript.Shell")  
OsType = ws.RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")    
    If OsType = "x86" then    
        strProgramFiles = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")  
    elseif OsType = "AMD64" then   
        strProgramFiles = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%")  
    end if 
GetProgramFilesPath = strProgramFiles
End Function
'-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. You went to a lot of trouble to download the program and test it, which was above and beyond, and very kind of you.

Unfortunately I think my wording about me testing the command in CMD gave the impression that I wanted the final result to also be run within a console. This is not what was intended. I have therefore reworded my question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh, reminds me of my vbscript days, now I use Ruby and it's just as simple as

```
´my_shell_command params´
```

However, back to your question: the shortest way to use ShellExecute is

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "application", "parameters", "dir", "verb", window
```

See [this](https://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) documentation for explanation of the parameters.

EDIT:
You have to pay attention at the quotes, they need to be passed to the shell also by using two quotes

eg `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe", """/Waterfox:C:\Program Files\Waterfox\Data\profile"""`

Comment: Here's what I wrote: `CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedyFox\speedyfox.exe", " /Waterfox:C:\Program Files\Waterfox\Data\profile"` It does not work. If I remove the parameter part and just run the executable, the window opens, so I know that part works (but that bit worked in my original script anyway). But as soon as I add required the switch, it won't work. I know that actual switch command is correct because it works from **Start > Run**